# How to get `__dirname` like Node.js using react native

Tags: node.js, react-native

I want to get current javascript script's dirname name, such as `__dirname` in node.js.
I haven't found the method in the document in react native , and I wonder how to achieve this purpose?
Or how can I locate the static file (e.g. .js)? For example like using `NSDocumentDirectory` to locate a file natively in iOS.

Comment: What do you want to use `__dirname` for?

Answer (score 3):

One way to do it would be to create a native module. Here's an example of a really simple one that just gets you a string, which you could customise for your exact requirements. In Xcode, create a new class:

```
//  DirName.h

#import "RCTBridgeModule.h"

@interface DirName : NSObject<RCTBridgeModule>

@end

//  DirName.m
#import "DirName.h"

@implementation DirName
- (void) get:(RCTResponseSenderBlock)callback {
    RCT_EXPORT();

    // Change this depending on what you want to retrieve:
    NSString* dirName = @"something";

    callback(@[dirName]);
}

@end
```

Then call it with:

```
var dirName = require('NativeModules').DirName;

dirName.get(dirName => {
    console.log(dirName);
});
```

However I'd caveat this. Have a think about what you're doing - do you definitely want to read the filesystem of your iOS device or do you want to use one of the other methods of grabbing documents which is available to you?

Comment: I suppose the question's author wanted to know how to make __dirname work so that modules using it will work w/o modification.